# Setting 1 or 0 to new Pandas column conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

A pretty straightforward pandas question:

If I have a dataframe as such:

```
   hour
 0  0
 1  1
 2  1
 3  2
 4  2
  ...
```

and I'd like to create a new column 'lunch' that'll have the value 1 if 11<=hour<=1 and 0 otherwise, what's the best and computationally quickest way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean 11 <= hour <= 1 , that condition can never be satisfied , so just set everything to 0 .

Comment: @anand at a guess, `hour` is a reading in 12 hour time, so it should wrap around. But without being able to check either am/pm or the date, then it would always be true.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could

```
In [231]: df['lunch'] = (df['hour']<=11) & (df['hour']<=1)

In [232]: df['lunch']
Out[232]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: lunch, dtype: bool

In [233]: df['lunch'].astype(int)
Out[233]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    0
Name: lunch, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 10):

You can have a vectorized approach (the minus operator is here to negate the boolean mask):

```
df['lunch'] = (-df.hour.isin(range(2,11))).astype(int)

Out[368]:
   hour  lunch
0     0      1
1     1      1
2     1      1
3     2      0
4     2      0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
>>> df['lunch']=df['hour'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= 11 or x <= 1 else 0)
>>> df
   hour  lunch
0     0      1
1     1      1
2     1      1
3     2      0
4     2      0
```